# Set a sub-form hidden field to visible, based on a check box status

Tags: vba, ms-access

C, Thank you for your input and encouragement! I have changed my form and script slightly, I am afraid I kept the if then statement as I am comfortable with the formatting.  The script now works when the 'On Open'event runs.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Me.ChkAlbumNotes.SetFocus

If Me.ChkAlbumNotes.Value = False Then
    Me.lblAlbumNotes.Visible = False
    Me.txtAlbumNotes.Visible = False
    Me.btnAlbumNotes.Visible = True
Else
    Me.lblAlbumNotes.Visible = True
    Me.txtAlbumNotes.Visible = True
    Me.btnAlbumNotes.Visible = False
End If
Me.TrackName.SetFocus
If Me.TrackName = " " Then
    Me.btnAddRecord.SetFocus
Else
Me.btnNextRecord.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

This is fine when the form opens for the first time but I have a set of navigation buttons that are installed by the application as Macros. I cannot add my script to the On_Click event when the button is clicked,  as On_Click is linked to the Macro. Is there a way to incorporate the script from the On_Load process to the pre-defined macro? Or can you suggest a neater way to achieve my requirements which are;

1. When the form opens,a check is made for the existence of a false value in the checkbox
   if the check box is set to false, then the Notes Text Box and label are hidden and the notes button is visible.
2. If the check box has a true value, then the Notes text box and label are made visible and the button is hidden.
3. On completion of the test I check the field Track Name
   if this is empty, I assume I am at the last record and give the Add New Record button the focus
4. If Track Name is not empty, then focus is set to Next Record button

when this button is clicked, the next record page opens and the process starts again.

Many Thanks

Mike

Comment: Since `Me.frmArtistSubform!chkNotes.SetFocus` does not produce an error, that checkbox must be visible already, so making it visible will not change anything. Since you don't change the visibility of any other control, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, if the subform is Continuous or Datasheet, setting a control visible on the subform will make it visible for ALL records. `If Then` is not needed nor does chkNotes need to have focus: `Me.somecontrol.Visible = Me.chkNotes` Can use Conditional Formatting to enable/disable controls per record.

Comment: Welcome! Don't worry about "pure" code, only improving what you know.

Comment: The 1st sentence describes a perfectly reasonable operation, but the posted code does not even attempt to do what is described. The code refers only to the checkbox and does *not even refer to other textboxes*. 1) Why would you expect the visibility of the other controls to change if the code does not even do anything with those textboxes?  Perhaps the posted code is not the complete code that you attempted?  2) Could you also explain why code is in the `recordID_GotFocus()` method? Maybe this event is not being called as you expect.

Comment: Hi, Thanks to both for your advice. I apologise for my stupid mistake, I did indeed post the wrong bits of my script. The snippet used while I was testing. I have now moved the notes elements of the sub form and placed them o the main form to try and minimise the complexity (well it is to me ). I have tried editing the code as suggested by Herr Kais and my understanding of it. But that did not work. I am trying to find a way to keep the notes txt box etc. hidden unless (a) the checkbox is true and there are already notes associated with the record or (B) I click the add notes button

Comment: Rather than waste your time with inane questions, I will just play and see f I can resolve the issue. Thanks again for the advice and suggestions already given

Comment: The point of Stack Overflow is not only to help individuals with an "immediately" need, but also to produce an archive of very useful questions & answers.  Many of us contribute to SO because we willingly donate our time to help others.  It is not wasting our time.  In fact, the best that you could do is to update your question (not just comments) with relevant code and improve the question based on feedback so that a proper answer can be given. I don't mean to guilt you into updating your question, but sometimes it's more of a waste when someone asks a question and then abandons it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Form_Current` event instead of `Form_Open` . This fires on starting the form (2 times) and everytime you move to another record.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.lblAlbumNotes.Visible = Me.ChkAlbumNotes.Value
Me.txtAlbumNotes.Visible = Me.ChkAlbumNotes.Value
Me.btnAlbumNotes.Visible = Not Me.ChkAlbumNotes.Value

If Me.TrackName = "" Then ' I suggest If Me.TrackName = " " being a typo and you want to check if empty ( that's why you should use vbNullString instead of "")
  Me.btnAddRecord.SetFocus
Else
  Me.btnNextRecord.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```